OSError: [WinError 10093] Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed
import sys
import select
print("Who is your best friend?")
print("You have ten seconds to answer!")
a, b, c = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 10)
if (a):
print("You stated your best friend name as: ",
sys.stdin.readline().strip())
else:
print("Your time is over")
**What is wrong in this code?
I use windows and I am getting
"OSError: [WinError 10093] Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed"

this error**

I tried to learn from geeksforgeeks and I get this error

select on windows can only operate on sockets, which stdin isn't.
